# Parse.com JavaScript Add Object from html form ERROR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I am writing a web app. I have used Parse.com's JavaScript library. Below is my JS code I get an error on the entire code (`<html>` tag):

```js
$('#NewSetForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var SetList = Parse.Object.extend("SetList");
    var setList = new SetList();

    setList.save({
        Tittle: $('#Topic').val(),
        WordOne: $('#wordone').val(),
        WordOneDefine: $('#wordonedefine').val(),
        WordTwo: $('#wordtwo').val(),
        WordTwoDefine: $('#wordtwodefine').val()
    }, {
        success: function (setList) {
            alert('Sucess');
            // The object was saved successfully.
        },
        error: function (setList, error) {
            alert('Faliled Contect us for support');
            // The save failed.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Go back through your code and try to match up the curly braces. You have five opening braces and only four closing. Proper indentation and formatting will help you a lot.

Comment: I edited the code assuming there was a typo but it's true, you might be missing the last `});` closing bracket/parenthesis

Comment: @JFK: I think you fixed the syntax error in your edit.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ The new code works. The only issue is the page is refreshing. Even though I have e.preventDefault();